# I am using Writer class in Java for UTF8 encoding output. How do I insert new line when writing?

Tags: java, utf-8, line, writer

My snippet code are as follow:

```
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("newFile.txt"); 
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
        Writer w = out;

        for(String str : arrayName) 
        {
            w.write("sample");
            //I wish to insert new line here
        }

        w.close();
```

Is there other way than to write a blank space manually? i.e. w.write("\n");

EDITED. Sorry for causing some misunderstanding regarding if I am looking for new line or blank space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For platform independent way use this:

```
w.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I forgot to specify the platform independent part in my question. This would do.

Answer (score 0):

w.write("\n");

Well apparently this answer was to short.

Comment: this is new line, no blank space (space character)

Comment: Hu? The subject say "How do I insert new line when writing?" But the body says something else. Try to edit the post to clarify what you want then.

Comment: Thank you people for trying to answer my question, even though I had poor language used. I found the answer I needed and my apology for any confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
PrintWriter bw = new PrintWriter(new File("newFile.txt"), "UTF-8");
...
bw.println("sample");
```

Comment: you may need to check your parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Read Java documentation [about special characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)
For blank space (space character) just do:

```
w.write(" ");
```